# How can I return only IDs from the `posts` REST endpoint?

Tags: wp-query, rest-api

I have the following code:

```
const FORMS = document.querySelectorAll(".search-form");

FORMS.forEach((form) => {
    const INPUT  = form.querySelector(".search-form__input");
    const BUTTON = form.querySelector(".search-form__button");

    BUTTON.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        wp.apiRequest({
            path: "wp/v2/posts",
            data: {
                search: INPUT.value,
            },
        }).then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });

    }, { passive: false });
});
```

`WP_Query` allows you to specify `"fields" => "ids"` to return *only* the post IDs. I only need the IDs from this request, so in order to cut down on database queries, I'd like to apply this same setting to the request. Is there a way to specify this in the REST API? I've tried setting `fields: "ids",` in the `data` property, but that doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Does `_fields : "id"` work?

Comment: Maybe create your own endpoint `(?my-endpoint=posts)` and use `get_posts( array('fields' => 'ids') );`?

Comment: **doing this does not cut down on database queries**, there will be just as many queries since WordPress will fetch the entire post regardless, and it takes just as many queries to fetch 5 rows of the post table as it does to fetch just the ID column of 5 rows of the post table. ***This will not improve database performance.***, at best you will get some minor savings on bandwidth which are then immediately eliminated when you make individual requests for each post. Also, if you have an object cache then the full post object is stored there already so it doesn't hit the database fetching it

Comment: @TomJNowell ah, gotcha, I had just assumed that it would be more performant returning less fields but I guess that's now how it works under the hood. Thanks for the info!

Comment: GraphQL is best at giving you precisely what you want and only what you want, but it doesn't scale, if it's scale and speed you want, then what you need is super cachable cookie cutter responses. Respond with the full post and do it from cache so the DB doesn't get hit at all, if you can remove the need to load WordPress entirely via something like Varnish or Nginx caches even better